# How can I setup an emulated device in Google Chrome to look like an A4 page?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a website using Bootstrap 4. I am trying to modify the CSS so that I get it looking how I want when I print the page to a PDF.

I have found the `Rendering` option to enable `Emulate CSS media type`. Enabling this means that the rules I see in the browser are the same ones that are applied during printing.

I want to setup an `Emulated Device` in Chrome so that it has the same size as various physical pages such as A4.

I am using a MacBook Pro 15" 2019 and so it should have a device pixel ratio of 2.

An A4 page is 210mm x 297mm.

What should the device width and height be set to?